# "ValueArray is not declared" exception when using spark map functions on dataset containing hash maps

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a class

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class TestInput implements Serializable {
    private Map<String, String> key1;
}
```

and json file

```
[{"key1": {"key2": "key3"}}]
```

I try to read and operate on the dataset using the spark map function

```
Dataset<TestInput> input = sparkSession.read().json(inputPath).as(Encoders.bean(TestInput.class));

Dataset<TestInput> output = input.map((MapFunction<TestInput, TestInput>) x -> x, Encoders.bean(TestInput.class));
```

input is read correctly as I'm able to view a response for input.show() but the response doesn't include the actual map

```
input.show()

+------+
|key1  |
+------+
|[key3]|
+------+
```

But the map function fails (which also converts it into a Java POJO) with error

```
A method named "valueArray" is not declared in any enclosing class nor any supertype, nor through a static import
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Also if I write input back to a file I do get back my original json so it probably does understand the map but is unable to transform to the required POJO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the schema of your `input`, you will see that `key1` is not a map but an array of string. This is why you're seeing the error. Set your schema to a map and you should be good to go.

Scala code

```
val expectedSchema = StructType(Seq(StructField("key1", MapType(StringType, StringType))))

val input = spark.read
  .schema(expectedSchema)
  .json(path)
  .as(Encoders.bean(classOf[TestInput]))

// key1 should be of map type
input.printSchema()

val out = input.map(
  (x: TestInput) => {
    x.setKey1((Map(("newkey", "newval")) ++ x.getKey1.asScala).asJava)
    x
  },
  Encoders.bean(classOf[TestInput]),
)

input.show(truncate = false)
out.show(truncate = false)
```